# Erlang syntax error before: 'end'

Tags: erlang

I have recently started learning erlang, but have encountered an error that just leaves me puzzled.

The error is `syntax error before: 'end'`  on the very last line. I have looked at examples an tried to find the error but I'm totally lost at the moment. Any Ideas?

```
ChannelToJoin = list:keysearch(ChannelName,1,State#server_st.channels),
case ChannelToJoin of
    % Channel exists.
    {value, Tuple} ->
        if 
            %User is not a member of the channel
            not list:member(UserID, Tuple) ->
            %Add the user to the channel
            Tuple#channel.users = list:append(Tuple#channel.users, [UserID]);


            % If the user is already a member of the channel.
            true -> true
        end;
    %Channel doesn't exist
    false ->
        %Create new channel and add the user to it.
        NewState = State#server_st{channels = list:append(State#server_st.channels, NewChannel = #channel{name = ChannelName, users = [UserID]}
end
```

Comment: Can you post more code? This looks fine to me, except that you are trying to update the `Tuple` record in the `if`. Remember: Variables in erlang are read-only

Answer (score 5):

The second to last line, `NewState = ...`, is missing two closing parentheses: `)}`

Also note that you can't use `lists:member` inside `if`, as function calls are not allowed inside guard expressions (which is what `if` lets you use).  Instead, use `case`:

```
case lists:member(UserID, Tuple#channel.users) of
    false ->
         %% Add the user to the channel
         ...;
    true ->
         %% Already a member
         ok
end
```